# How do I "shrink" this matrix's width

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, matrices

I'd like to shrink the width of the following diagonal matrix:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
    -V_1V_2b_{21} & & & & \\
     & -V_2V_3b_{32} & & & \\
     & & -V_1V_3b_{13} & & \\
     & & & -V_3V_4b_{34} & \\
     & & & & -V_1V_4b_{41}
\end{bmatrix}
```

which looks like this
[image]

However, this matrix is taking up too much space horizontally, so is there a way for me to (easily) "shrink" it to look like below?

[image]

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: use `\hspace{-3em}` between each column  - modify dimension to suit

Comment: Wow. That was indeed quick and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `\arraycolsep` to be a negative value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begingroup
\setlength\arraycolsep{-5pt}
\begin{bmatrix}
    -V_1V_2b_{21} & & & & \\
     & -V_2V_3b_{32} & & & \\
     & & -V_1V_3b_{13} & & \\
     & & & -V_3V_4b_{34} & \\
     & & & & -V_1V_4b_{41}
\end{bmatrix}
\endgroup
\]

\end{document}
```

`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are used to keep the change local.

Answer (score 0):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337013/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\shrink{\hspace{-3em}}
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    -V_1V_2b_{21}\shrink & & & & \\
    & -V_2V_3b_{32}\shrink & & & \\
    & & -V_1V_3b_{13}\shrink & & \\
    & & & -V_3V_4b_{34} \shrink& \\
    & & & & -V_1V_4b_{41}
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following I use a single column array, with entries shifted according to a predefined factor of the widest entry, which can be chosen with an optional argument (default 0.5).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\diagonal}{ O{0.5} m }
 {% #1 = indent factor, #2 = list of entries
  \gouhaha_diagonal:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% a box for measuring the entries, a length for storing the max
\box_new:N \l__gouhaha_diagonal_box
\dim_new:N \l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim

% a sequence for storing the entries
\seq_new:N \l__gouhaha_diagonal_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gouhaha_diagonal:nn
 {
  % store the entries
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__gouhaha_diagonal_seq { #2 }
  % let's get the max width
  \dim_zero:N \l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__gouhaha_diagonal_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__gouhaha_diagonal_box { $##1$ }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn { \l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim } { \box_wd:N \l__gouhaha_diagonal_box }
     }
   }
  % now set the length to the overlap (plus the \arraycolsep)
  \dim_set:Nn \l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim { #1\l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim }
  % make the matrix
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \l__gouhaha_diagonal_seq \__gouhaha_diagonal_entry:nn
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gouhaha_diagonal_entry:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 1 } { \\ }
  \hspace{ \int_eval:n {(#1-1)}\l__gouhaha_diagonal_dim }
  #2
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\diagonal{-V_1V_2b_{21}, -V_2V_3b_{32}, -V_1V_3b_{13}, -V_3V_4b_{34}, -V_1V_4b_{41}}
\]

\[
\diagonal[0.25]{-V_1V_2b_{21}, -V_2V_3b_{32}, -V_1V_3b_{13}, -V_3V_4b_{34}, -V_1V_4b_{41}}
\]

\[
\diagonal[0.75]{-V_1V_2b_{21}, -V_2V_3b_{32}, -V_1V_3b_{13}, -V_3V_4b_{34}, -V_1V_4b_{41}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\seq_indexed_map_function:NN` function is very useful, because it provides both the loop index together with the current sequence item.